# Prove Complex Limits from first principle definition

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Show from first principles, that is using the definition of limit, that

$$\lim_{z\to i}\frac{z-1}{z^2+1} = \infty$$

Please can someone actually show me the procedure, struggling to understand it when people describe with words

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{z\to i } \frac{z-1}{z^2 + 1} = \lim_{z\to i } \left|\frac{z-1}{(z-i)(z+i)}\right| \\ =\lim_{z\to i } \frac{|z-1|}{|z-i||z+i|}$$

$$\rm Now,\  as\  z\to i, \ |z-i|\to 0$$
$$\implies f(z) \to \infty$$

Comment: numerator term is $z-1$, not $z-i$.

Comment: How would you do this using the definition of a limit though??

Comment: This is actually not sufficient, Tim. In complex worlds, right and left sided limits are not a good idea. Sam Harpers Limit is more: It says, no matter which way you approach "i", the limit of the fraction is always "\infty" meaning that the absolute value of the fraction goes to $\infty$ as $z$ goes to $i$.

Comment: @sranthrop but you've got i on the bottom and its 1 on the bottom??

Comment: @sranthrop so don't we have to put the modulus sign for showing that it is the limit of modulus, or is it this way only for complex numbers?

Comment: @Tim For complex numbers the symbol $\lim_{z \to a}f(z)= \infty$ is by definition equivalent to $\lim_{z \to a}|f(z)|= +\infty$. For example, $\lim_{z \to 0} 1/z = \infty$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What on earth is "$z > i$" supposed to mean?

Comment: i realise my stupidity